# How do I set the default properties in an AOSP build?

Tags: android, android-source

Where can I change the default `Android` device properties in my custom `AOSP` build?

For example:

- GPS - ON;
- Sync - ON;
- Brightness - AUTO;
- Bluetooth - OFF;
- WiFi - OFF;
- Sound - default sound;
- Vibrate when ring - OFF;

These settings should be defined in the build so they are already in their correct state once build is loaded.

Is there a centralized file/folder for all the settings? Or a `Settings` application that gathers by itself settings from all `Android` platform modules?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are two main places I usually check for defaults:

```
/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml
```

and:

```
/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml
```

Its also worth checking the device directory for overlays which just override the original files:

```
/device/<company-name>/<product-name>/overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml
```

Default wallpaper usually hardcoded to:

```
/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-nodpi/default_wallpaper.jpg
```

Default volume levels for various streams(int[] DEFAULT_STREAM_VOLUME):

```
/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/AudioSystem.java
```

Comment: thanks for info. I would like to know locations of these config files in built Android....like /data/xxx, Do you know? I want changed values, like default value for volume is 10, user changes to 15. So where should i read property having value 15.

Comment: Most of them are in settings provider, it has an apk and also dynamic DB in /data/..

Comment: what about enable roaming or set lock mode (none, slide, ...) ? it didn't find it in these 2 files.

Comment: @skoperst How about default system language? Thanks.

Comment: Its the first language in the locale list in the device makefile. The result is stored in build.prop

Comment: And don't forget the vendor repositories like `vendor/xos/`, `vendor/cm/`or `vendor/aosp/`