# How to modify application settings in a custom Android ROM?

Tags: android, settings, customization, cyanogenmod, rom

here's my problem :

I've already done some research with Google, Stack Overflow and XDA Developers forums but I didn't even find a related question.

I'm trying to customize [**this**](http://www.phonandroid.com/forum/cyanogenmod-7-2-t46609.html) CyanogenMod ROM so the "Unknown sources" checkbox (in Settings > Applications) is checked by default after the installation of the ROM using ClockWorkMod, but I can't seem to find where to do it.

I searched into the following APK files using [**apktool**](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) :

- /system/framework/framework-res.apk
- /system/app/Settings.apk
- /system/app/SettingsProvider.apk
- /system/app/ApplicationsProvider.apk
- /system/app/PackageInstaller.apk
- /system/app/CertInstaller.apk

but I didn't find anything.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out I didn't search hard enough.

For those who are interested, the file to edit is located into **SettingsProvider.apk**.
You have to decompile it (with [**apktool**](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)) and edit the file **SettingsProvider/res/values/bools.xml**, replacing this line :

```
<bool name="def_install_non_market_apps">false</bool>
```

by this one :

```
<bool name="def_install_non_market_apps">true</bool>
```

And then, recompile, etc.

Hope this helps.

Source : [xda-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1328004)

Comment: Also you may consider changing such values in CM sources, as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770639/how-to-set-default-properties-in-aosp. In my case file `overlay/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml` defines `def_install_non_market_apps`. Seems that app packages usually have config files in res/values/config.xml, which you can redefine in overlay for your device