# How to set system volume to maximum in AOSP source

Tags: android, system, android-source, volume

currently i am working on AOSP source and one of my requirement is to set system volume to max level, i go through following link and its specified file but i could't find any volume related settings [How to set default properties in AOSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770639/how-to-set-default-properties-in-aosp), is there any one who have done it, please guide me to it.

Comment: Are you talking about default level on boot or the ability to change the volume?

Comment: default level on boot which i need to set to max level.

Comment: It may be irelevant for OP, but for anyone other, if you mean set the volume to max like you do in settings, there is an array default stream volumes in AudioManager ( or AudioService - don't remember in which of them ) which you could modify. Make sure to check the other array containing the max values for each stream.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main places I would look for:
1. `/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml` 
Inside you'll find the `config_soundEffectVolumeDb` which control the default volume.

But AOSP developing is never that easy - **This file might be overwrriten by specific vendor** so you will have to chek here too:
2.`/device/<companyname>/<productname>/overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml`

Comment: do you have any idea related its value which takes sound to max level cos i dnt have much knowledge abt db values.

Comment: Big answer - no. From what i managed to understand it will try to take to the higher level and will get "stuck" on max

Comment: hmm let me try with value 0db since it takes -6db