# How to disable HDMI CEC in aosp build?

Tags: android-source, hdmi

I have Android 7.1 SDK and I want to set CEC disabled by default. (Now the default is 'on')
I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770639/how-do-i-set-the-default-properties-in-an-aosp-build) but CEC is not there.  Also there is some cec files in these paths but they don't config CEC and are only sources:

```
> ./vendor/amlogic/frameworks/services/hdmicec/libhdmi_cec/HdmiCecControl.cpp
> ./hardware/libhardware/include/hardware/hdmi_cec.h
> ./common/drivers/amlogic/cec/hdmi_ao_cec.c
```

Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same needs on you in android-o.You can make changes in these two places：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qENha.png)